# Outlook 2013: Two views of the same folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Using Outlook 2013, I'd like to have two views of my Inbox handy, one showing the Message Preview (the first line of each email), and the other without.

I can't find a way to do this, other than to change the setting back and forth (which takes 4 menu choices, each time).  Saving the view doesn't save the Message Preview setting.

I'd like either to:

- Add another "link" to the Folder in the Folder pane, showing the same folder, but with Message Preview on
- Add a hotkey or mouse click, to turn Message Preview on or off
- Add new Views, one with Preview on, one with it off

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do here is to add 2 buttons to a HOME tab of the ribbon to turn the Message Preview on or off.

To do this, right-click the ribbon and select **Customize the Ribbon**. Select **Main Tabs** above the list on the left side. Expand **View -> Arrangements -> Message Preview**. On the right list expand **Home (Mail)** and click the **New Group** button in the bottom. Name the group (say, "Message Preview") using the **Rename** button. Now click **Off** item on the left list and click **Add>>** button in the middle. Repeat for **1 Line** item. Click OK.

Now you can turn the message preview on/off with a single click of a mouse (actually double because of the confirmation, but anyway).